# MySql stored procedure rows issue

Tags: mysql

I have this stored procedure:

```
    CREATE DEFINER=`admin`@`%` PROCEDURE `GetTickets4Card`(
        IN p_TicketID int, 
        OUT p_returnvalue int
    )

BEGIN

    SELECT idbookingstickets
        INTO @p_returnvalue
        FROM bookingstickets 
        WHERE TicketId = p_TicketID;
        
        /* Return value accordingly */
        IF mysqll_affected_rows = 0 THEN  SET p_returnvalue = 0;
        /*
        ELSE
            SELECT * FROM BookingsTicketsCollected WHERE p_returnalue = idtickets;
            if mysqll_affected_rows = 0 THEN SET p_returnvalue = -1;
            END IF;
            */
        END IF;
    END
```

It gives me the following error: "Result consisted of more than one row". It may have something to do with `mysql_affected_rows` , but I have no idea, I want to know if the sql statement returns 1 row or not, any ideas?

Call code:

```
set @p_returnvalue = 0;
call yourTICKETbox_LIVE_DB.GetTickets4Card("aabb188e-6adc-11e5-9770-061de6653ea3", @p_returnvalue);
select @p_returnvalue;
```

Comment: Select into only allows 1 value. Please expand your question to include what you want to achieve, add sample data and expected output as text.. aslo @p_returnvalue is not the same as p_returnvalue (which is not declared)

Comment: I want to know if the sql statement returns 1 row or not, any ideas - count instead?

Comment: `mysqll_affected_rows` - what is it? MySQL does not know...

Comment: `OUT p_returnvalue int` and `INTO @p_returnvalue` - these are 2 different variables.

Comment: It's returning more than one row. When there's more than one booking with the same ticket ID, which one do you want to use in the `BookingsTicketsCollected` query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `SELECT ... INTO variable`, the query must return at most one row. If you only care whether there are any matching rows, you can use the `EXISTS()` function.

```
SET p_returnvalue = EXISTS(
    SELECT 1
    FROM bookingstickets 
    WHERE TicketId = p_TicketID);
```

BTW, the MySQL equivalent to the PHP function `mysqli_affected_rows()` is `ROW_COUNT()`.